# Using Pytest to test an 'if statement' in a DJango module

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

This is the environment

**settings.py**

```
from decouple import config

STEMMER = config('STEMMER', default = 'porter')
```

**views.py**

```
from my_project import settings
from nltk import PorterStemmer, LancasterStemmer

if settings.STEMMER == 'porter':
    stemmer = PorterStemmer()
elif settings.STEMMER == 'lancaster':
    stemmer = LancasterStemmer()


def one_function():
    """Do some stuffs with the stemmer"""


def another_function():
    """Do another stuffs with the stemmer"""
```

The question is how to create a test using `Pytest` that covers both cases?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would split the tests up. You can then edit the value of the setting in the test, e.g.:

```
def test():
    settings.STEMMER = "porter"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have already tried it and it does not work. Also, tried to (i) created `pytest.fixtures`; (ii) used the `settings` helpers documented [here](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html). I believe it does not work, because the if is in the module level, not in the function level. But, I would'nt put the if statement inside each method.